# How to have summary API in my own wikidata

Tags: summary, wikidata, wikidata-api

I would like to have the summary API to show in the tooltip just like in wikipedia page.

The example could be
https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Fixed_point_(mathematics)

But then this is not one of the default end point. Is there any extension out there I have to install? Or this one is a custom one? The goal is to get a small part of text and image if available